# JQuery - Button triggers multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, dynamic

I have a checklist, where I get a list when I click on a Checkbox. I can check more than one Checkbox - so I get more lists.  I add at then end of each list a button, through JQuery. My Code for the button looks like this:

```
//Add a button to the previous list:
function add() {
    $(".list:last").append("<div id='button'><input type='button' class='click' id='feld' name='feld' value='+'/>Add new listfield</div>");
}
```

When I click on the button, I get a new Checkbox with empty Textfield:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Variables for counting
    var utxtname = 0;
    var ucheckname = 0;
    var utxtid = 1;
    var ucheckid = 1;
    var uctxtname = 1;
    var uccheckname= 1;

    //Function for the buttons with the same class ".click"

    $(document).on('click', '.click', function() {
        var utxtname ='utxtfield'+uctxtname;
        var ucheckname ='uchecklist'+uccheckname;
        $(this).closest(".list").append("<br><input type='checkbox' name=' "+ucheckname+"' id='"+ucheckid+"' checked><input type='textfield' name ='"+utxtname+"' id='"+utxtid+"'/>");
        uctxtname += 1;
        uccheckname += 1;
        utxtid += 1;
        ucheckid += 1;
    });

});
```

My Problem:

When I generate more than one Button, the function triggers multiple times. If I have 3 lists with 3 generated buttons, my function generates 3 buttons if I click on a button. I knew the reason for my mistake. It's because I have 3 buttons with the same class, so it triggers the function multiple times. I just can't figure out how I can solve this problem. I tried so many methods to prevent this. For example unbind the function and bind it again. I also tried to dynamically add button with unique functions, but I couldnt get this. 
Any Ideas how can I solve this problem easier?

Comment: I don't think your explanation is right. It should only trigger for the button that you clicked on, even if you have other buttons with the same class. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You're generating html elements with the same id's in your `add` function. It won't solve your problem, but it is something you should change (you either aren't using them and therefor don't need them or you are using them and are not going to get reliable results).

Comment: I will try to code it on JSFiddle.

Comment: I'd need to see more of the DOM code, but it's possible that the other buttons are in the bubble path (i.e., are in a straight path from the clicked button to the document) and therefor get triggered too. "jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector." http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Yes, please show us a fiddle.

Comment: Mb use  $('.click').on('click', function(event, name) {...}); construction and could you create a jsFiddle for it pls so we could test your case. Thanks

Comment: @eu.vl That's never going to work, because the event handler is registered before the buttons are generated.

Comment: @gpgekko yeah, just tried it

Comment: I think I will need some more time, since I can't use PHP on JSFiddle. I have to reconstruct it with HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3Zb/12/ 
I dont know why, but it works on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Preprocezzor That can only mean your DOM is different

Comment: Probably it's because I get some parts of the page through Ajax from another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inner function is the simplest solution, but may lead to a memory leak. This is just a more choice.

```
function add() {
    var $button = $("<div id='button'><input type='button' class='click' id='feld' name='feld' value='+'/>Add new listfield</div>");
    $(".list:last").append($button);
    $button.click(function(){
        /*process here*/
    });
}
```

Just for remind, the button may not release , since click function is bound. If you remove in your own code, please add `$("button").unbind("click");`

Comment: @Navin Thanks, I am new to stack over flow. And just finger out how to write format code from your edition. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Just use `Off()` in jquery  before the `on()` statement

Comment: use event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
e.PreventDefault();
```

statement to prevent multiple trigger.

Comment: I think that whenever you're creating checkbox the click event is registering.

Comment: The method should be `e.preventDefault()` Notice the lowercase `p`